# Reload only one attribute mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid5

I have `model` object implementing `Mongoid::Document`

`model` has an attribute called `name`

I need to reload only `name` of `model`

Is there something shorter than

`Model.only(:name).find(model.id).name`

like `model.reload(:name)`

Answer (score 0):

Only rewrite the reload method:

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def reload(field = nil)
      field.nil? ? super() : eval("#{self.class.name}.only(:#{field}).find('#{self.id}').#{field}")
    end
  end
end
```